# Como realizar un conteo de una consulta que ya usa un count

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite, count

Necesito obtener el numero de registros de esa consulta

```
select Atenciones.IdAtencion,count(*) as partos
        from Atenciones left outer join 
            AtencionesDiagnosticos on Atenciones.IdAtencion=AtencionesDiagnosticos.IdAtencion left outer join
            Servicios on IdServicioEgreso=Servicios.IdServicio
        where  Atenciones.IdServicioEgreso=302 and AtencionesDiagnosticos.IdDiagnostico between '9628' and '9654' 
        and (Atenciones.FechaEgreso between '20220801' and '20220831')
        group by Atenciones.IdAtencion
```

Intente realizarlo asi, pero se dispara el tiempo de ejecucion de 0 a 10 seg

```
with TablaC as(
    Select Atenciones.IdAtencion,count(*) as partos
    from Atenciones left outer join 
        AtencionesDiagnosticos on Atenciones.IdAtencion=AtencionesDiagnosticos.IdAtencion left outer join
        Servicios on IdServicioEgreso=Servicios.IdServicio
    where  Atenciones.IdServicioEgreso=302 and AtencionesDiagnosticos.IdDiagnostico between '9628' and '9654' 
    and (Atenciones.FechaEgreso between '20220801' and '20220831')
    group by Atenciones.IdAtencion
    )
select count(*)from TablaC
```

Alguna otra forma que optimice el tiempo de ejecución?

Comment: bueno te diría que uses subquery, pero como no es una cte recursiva entonces no hay diferencia; puedes hacer uso de índices

Comment: Pero, ¿ese valor no está ya en `partos`? No entiendo para que la metes de nuevo en una sub-consulta ¿?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asi logre que la ejeccionser de 0 a 1s

```
declare @tem_table table(num int)
insert @tem_table
    Select count(*) as partos
    from Atenciones left outer join 
        AtencionesDiagnosticos on Atenciones.IdAtencion=AtencionesDiagnosticos.IdAtencion left outer join
        Servicios on IdServicioEgreso=Servicios.IdServicio
    where  Atenciones.IdServicioEgreso=302 and AtencionesDiagnosticos.IdDiagnostico between '9628' and '9654' 
    and (Atenciones.FechaEgreso between '20220801' and '20220831')
    group by Atenciones.IdAtencion
    
select count(*) from @tem_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Conceptualmente quieres contar los distintos `IdAtencion`, por lo que podrías emplear el modificador `DISTINCT` de la función `COUNT()`:

```
select  COUNT(DISTINCT Atenciones.IdAtencion)
        from Atenciones 
        left outer join AtencionesDiagnosticos 
             on Atenciones.IdAtencion=AtencionesDiagnosticos.IdAtencion 
        left outer join Servicios 
             on IdServicioEgreso=Servicios.IdServicio
        where  Atenciones.IdServicioEgreso=302 
               and AtencionesDiagnosticos.IdDiagnostico between '9628' and '9654' 
               and (Atenciones.FechaEgreso between '20220801' and '20220831')
```

Los tiempos deberían ser similares a la de la consulta original con el `GROUP BY`, francamente no se por que una expresión de tabla te degrada tanto la performance.

Comment: buena respuesta amigo, pero el tiempo de ejecución es de 10s, encontré una opción que ejecuta en 0s, asi cuando la consulta le agrego a un cursor donde vere de todas los servicios no se extendiera mucho, ahí les comparto